# The PowerShell Form button text is not correctly aligned and blurry

Tags: winforms, powershell, button, fonts

The font is different from the MessageBox and custom Form button.

```
$size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 154);

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
$form.BackColor = [System.Drawing.SystemColors]::Window;
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen";
$form.MinimumSize = $size;
$form.ShowIcon = $false;
$form.Topmost = $true;
$form.Text = $Title;
$form.Size = $size;

$ok = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button;
$ok.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
$ok.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true;
$ok.DialogResult = "OK";
$ok.Text = "OK";
$ok.Anchor = 8;

$form.Controls.Add($ok);

$form.ShowDialog();
```

The font is not aligned verticaly on center and is more blurry.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do some quick tests. It appears that there is indeed a difference in the appearance between a `Forms.Button` and the `Windows.MessageBox` -or `Forms.MessageBox`

**MessageBox:**

Call:

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Test", $null ,'OkCancel')
```

Result:

[image: MessageBox Button]

**FormButton:**

Call:

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$testButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$testButton.Text = "OK"
$form.Controls.Add($testButton)
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Results:

[image: FormButton]

My first through was that maybe there is a diffence between the `System.Windows` namespace and the `Windows.Forms` namespace.

I then ran another test to call the `MessageBox` class for the `Windows.Forms` namespace. Surprisingly this test showed the same font and alignment with the `System.Windows.MessageBox`

**Windows.Forms.MessageBox:**

Call:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Test")
```

Results:

[image: SysWindowsMessage]

My assumption would be that the default text / alignment in the `Windows.Forms.Button` is not the same as the `Windows.MessageBox` or `Forms.MessageBox`. All I can conclude is there must of been a different MS developer working on the `.MessageBox` class then there was working on `Forms.Button`class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like text alignment of a `System.Windows.Forms.Button` by default is 'MiddleCenter', where the MessageBox uses 'BottomCenter'.

Try different TextAlign possibilities for the `$testButton.TextAlign` setting.

On my Windows 7 machine below addition to your code

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$testButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$testButton.Text = "OK"
$testButton.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::BottomCenter
$form.Controls.Add($testButton)
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

$form.Dispose()
```

produces this

[image]

P.S. you can shorten the line by just entering the enum name like `$testButton.TextAlign = 'BottomCenter'`, but by using the full `[System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::` will give you intellisense.

You can also find the different enum values [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.contentalignment)

Comment: But is still blurry compared to the MessageBox text.

Comment: @Marian The blurry text is not PowerShell's doing, but a common problem in Windows 10. Try googling for a solution that helps on your system. A good starting point for that is [here](https://superuser.com/a/1287430) or [there](https://www.devicetricks.com/blurry-text-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

.TextAlign = "Center"

Answer (score -1):

Found to disable the default text rendering:

```
[Windows.Forms.Application]::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault($false);
```